# Form Submit Button Pop-Up Box Php/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

im able to insert data in mysql and redirect to my index page. but my confirmation alert box wont pop-up after clicking my button/ submit form, whats the problem? :(

php/javascript page(seatplan_occupied.php):

```
<script>
   function formOccupied()
   {
   document.getElementByName("formOccupied").innerHTML;

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to confirm your purchase?") == true)
    {
        alert("Yeay! You bought ticket/s");
        <?php
        include("databaseconnect.php");

        if (mysql_query("UPDATE tblseatchart SET seatSTATUS='Occupied' WHERE seatSTATUS='Selected'"));

        include("index.php");
        ?>
    }

    else
    {
       alert("Owh No! You Cancelled to confirm... Whats wrong?");
    }

}
</script>
```

html page:

```
<form name = "formOccupied" method="post" onSubmit="occupied()" action="seatplan_occupied.php">
<input name = "btnSubmit" type = "submit" value="CONFIRM">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems:

1. You created a function called `formOccupied` but are trying to call a function called `occupied`.
2. That function appears to be defined in `seatplan_occupied.php` but you are trying to call it using a form in `index.html`. JavaScript runs in the current page, not the next one.

---

Other things to note:

- PHP inside a JavaScript `if` statement [will run regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programmin)
- You haven't done anything to stop the form submitting if the user selects *Cancel* on the `confirm`
- There is no `getElementByName` method, its `getElementsByName` and it returns a NodeList, not an element, but you'd be better off using `getElementById` (and using `id` instead of the obsolete `name` on the form) or, event better, [using `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) combined with the `this` keyword instead of the `onsubmit` attribute

Comment: could you show me how its done? im not a pro in programming. im not sure how to use the addEventListener with the this keyword.